# Python image scraper works when run alone but not when called from somewhere else

Tags: python

Python 2.7

Ubuntu 12.04

I'm trying to put together an image scraper, I've done this before with no problems but right now I'm stuck at a certain point.

I get a list of image links from wherever, either a web page or a user, let's assume that they are valid links.

The site I am scraping is imgur, some of the links won't work because I haven't added support for them (single files), I have the code for getting the links for each image from an album page down, that works and returns links like:

```
http://i.imgur.com/5329B8H.jpg #(intentionally broken link)
```

The image_download function as I have it in my actual program:

```
def image_download(self, links):
    for each in links:
        url = each
        name = each.split('/')[-1]
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        with open(name, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
                if not chunk:
                    break

            f.write(chunk)
```

The image_download function as I have it for testing to be run on it's own:

```
def down():
    links = ['link-1', 'link-2']
    for each in links:
        name = each.split('/')[-1]
        r = requests.get(each, stream=True)
        with open(name, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
                if not chunk:
                    break
                f.write(chunk)
```

Now here's the thing, the second one works.
They both take the same input, they both do the same thing.
The first one *does* return a file with the correct name and extension but the file-size is different, say 960b as opposed to the second one which returns a file of about 200kb.

When I print the request both return a response of 200, I've tried printing the output at different points and as far as I can see they operate in exactly the same way with exactly the same data, they just don't give back the same information.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indent `f.write(chunk)` one more time. You are only writing the last chunk to the file right now.

The corrected function will look like this:

```
def image_download(self, links):
    for each in links:
        url = each
        name = each.split('/')[-1]
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        with open(name, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
                if not chunk:
                    break

                f.write(chunk) #This has been indented to be in the for loop.
```